# CSS3 transform issue in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions, mozilla

I am having a strange issue while implying a transform effect at firebox browser.

**Demo Link**

```
"http://codepen.io/uzess/pen/zvOgmd"
```

**Issue Explanation**

1) The code works fine for chrome and safari, but the transform effect is not showing properly at Mozilla Firebox

2) The code also works fine for three images in all the browsers, but it didn't work properly at Firebox for four and more images.

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Regards,

Biplab

Comment: Why does your code have only prefixed versions of `@keyframes`?!

Comment: Code doesn't work even @keyframe is kept :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like when you add more than 3 items, there occurs errors ( irregularity ).
It is due to the css display properties.
Use 
`<div class="col-md-2" style="display: list-item">`

or 
`<div class="mane1 contact" style="display: list-item">`

Main thing here is `display: list-item`.

Please see fixed version here http://codepen.io/codersantosh/pen/yYLOvP

Comment: Thank you very much, it saved my day :)